# Can't open app exported from Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

I exported my Mac app from the Organizer a few days ago without problems. I chose "Export > Export as Mac Application"

Today I did a new build with exactly the same steps. The exported app works on my machine, but when I distributed it internally to other devs, they get a **"App is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Trash"** error message.

It's apparently a Gatekeeper issue, but it doesn't even work if Gatekeeper is set to allow all apps.

Any clues?

PS: SIP is disabled on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the `use_frameworks!` setting in the `Podfile`. Once I removed that the app ran again on the other machines.